# Custom styles not work in new theme Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, css, less

Read a lot: [Create a storefront theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)
My steps:

1. Create a theme directory `app/design/frontend/My-vendor/default`
2. Copy all files from `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma` to `app/design/frontend/My-vendor/default`
3. Change files: registration, theme. So now I have my theme same luma.
4. I chose in admin-panel my new theme.
5. Important remove `pub/static`.
   Now I try add or change style theme, chenge `_theme.less` in `app/design/frontend/My-vendor/default/web/css/source`, but not have changes. Why? What i do wrong? I always delete `pub/static`. Realy need help.

Comment: you remove `var/generation`  and clear the cache

Comment: var/generation no, clear the cache yes.

Comment: ok give the folder permission in the generation and cache 777

Comment: ok welcomeThank you